# How can I make one component of my app reload while keeping the rest of my components from not reloading?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been building a review app using Vue.js that gets a some random fact (using the API https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en), and then allows the user to give their feedback about the fact in a form that contains radio and text inputs. After they submit their feedback, it gets recorded and displayed in a list, which is another component set under the form. But I have been running into a block, because by default, once the information in the form gets submitted, the page reloads. This causes whatever information the user submitted to be wiped.

So, I tried modifying the form by adding `prevent` to the html form tag (i.e. `<form v-on:submit.prevent="handleSubmit">`) so that the whole page would not reload, but that caused another problem to rise– without reloading the page, a new sentence from the API cannot be retrieved.

I have the two components in Vue set up as follows:

```
//first component
<template>
<div v-if="randomFact">
    <h3><span>Random fact: </span>{{this.randomFact.text}}</h3>
    <form v-on:submit='handleSubmit'>
        <input type="radio" name="reaction" id="positive" value="positive" v-model="reaction"> 
        <label for="positive">Positive</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="reaction" id="neutral" value="neutral" v-model="reaction">
        <label for="neutral">Neutral</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="reaction" id="negative" value="negative" v-model="reaction">
        <label for="negative">Negative</label><br>
        <br>
        <label for="feedback">Feedback</label>
        <br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="feedback" v-model="feedback"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main.js';
import Review from '../classes/review.js';

export default {
    name: "review-detail",
    data(){
        return {
            randomFact:"",
            reaction: "",
            feedback:""
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        fetch('https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en').then(response=> response.json())
       .then(randomFact=> this.randomFact= randomFact)
       .catch(error=> console.log(error))
    },
    methods: {
        handleSubmit(){
            let review = new Review(this.randomFact.text, this.reaction, this.feedback);
            eventBus.$emit('review-recorded', review)
        }
    } 
}
</script>

//second component
<template>
    <div>
        <ul id="reviews" v-bind="reviews">
            <li v-for="review in reviews" :key="review.reaction">
                <p>Random fact: {{review.randomFact}}</p>
                <p>Reaction: {{review.reaction}}</p>
                <p>Feedback: {{review.feedback}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main.js';
import Review from '../classes/review.js';

export default {
    name:'reviews-list',
    data(){
        return{
            reviews:[],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        eventBus.$on('review-recorded', (review)=>{
            this.reviews.push(review);
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

So how can I reload the first component to get new information from the API while not reloading the second component? Am I setting up the interaction between the two components of my Vue app incorrectly? I just want to have information from the form of my first component recorded and displayed by my second component, while having my first component reload to get new random facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitelly need to prevent the browser from submiting the form. `<form v-on:submit.prevent="handleSubmit">` should be the way to go.

In your `handleSubmit` method, you need to use a HTTP request in the background to talk to your API. [Axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) is a very popular solution you may want to take a look at.

There are plenty of libraries to solve this, depending on your needs. I'd
go with axios, as it is widely known and used, so it is easy to find
good tutorials and help with that. You could in fact use standard `XMLHttpRequest` as well, but that is not your best option when using Vue.js.